# Getting subcaptions into the list of figures without having a real subfigure

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, subfloats, subcaption

I gave searching my best shot, but no luck. Here's my problem: I use `\phantomsubcaption` from the `subcaption` package to do referencing, but I also want some sort of marker in the List of Figures with a short description of each panel. I've tried other command combinations from the `subcaption` package, but no luck so far. Does memoir have something built in to help me, or should I just give up?

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
        \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}} %just for aesthetics
        \newcommand{\callsubfig}[1]{\textbf{(#1)}} % how I reference subfigs in my captions
\usepackage[style=base,labelfont=bf]{caption} % I bold my caption titles.


\begin{document}
\newdimen\LoFindent
\LoFindent = \parindent

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*
\newpage
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Intro}
Intro to my topic. Here's a figure to clarify. (\fref{fig:introFig})

\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
    {\fbox{Figure graphics that have 2 panels in one PDF file.}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:introFigA}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:introFigB}}
    \caption[Full Caption Title for ToC]{Caption title appears in text and is much longer than what appears in the LoF, which is good because this is long.
        \callsubfig{\subref{subfig:introFigA}} Explaining the first part, then\ldots
        \callsubfig{\subref{subfig:introFigB}} Explaining the second. But how do I get subcaption titles into the LoF?
        }\label{fig:introFig}
\end{figure}

for an idea of what I want my LoF to look like, see \fref{fig:example}.


\begin{figure}[!b]
ToC Title for Fig 1.1 \dotfill \pageref{fig:introFig}

\hspace{\LoFindent} subtitle for subfig A

\hspace{\LoFindent} subtitle for subfig B


ToC Title for Fig 1.2 \dotfill \pageref{fig:example}

\caption{What I want my LoF to look like (content-wise, of course)}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides its own interface to subfloat setting and referencing (and is generally incompatible with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and friends). Use `\subbottom[<LoF entry>][<subtitle>]{<stuff>}` (or `\subtop` for top-placed sub-captions).

Comment: I'd rather not have to go back through and fix everything, especially since I don't always use memoir. Is there a way to get this working with the `subcaption` package?

Comment: @DocBuckets My first idea was "Use `\captionlistentry` within a `subfigure` environment instead of `\phantomcaption` but to my surprise I totally forgot to adapt `\captionlistentry` to my `subcaption` package. I will do this upcoming Monday (17th of June), is this sufficient for you or do you need a much quicker solution? (BTW: I just opened a new ticket for that issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/13/ )

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt That is plenty soon and a great solution. I'm not used to how open the LaTeX community is - it's pretty awesome that the dev of the package is responding to my question with a change to the package itself. Many thanks!

Comment: @DocBuckets Done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea was using `\captionlistentry` within a `subfigure` environment instead of `\phantomcaption` since `\captionlistentry` will create a list-entry and a reference (which can be utilized with `\label` and `\ref`) while `\phantomcaption` only create a reference:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
        \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}} %just for aesthetics
        \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{boldparens}{\textbf{(#2)}} % how I reference subfigs in my captions
\captionsetup{style=base,labelfont=bf,subrefformat=boldparens} % I bold my caption titles.

\begin{document}
\newdimen\LoFindent
\LoFindent = \parindent

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*
\newpage
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Intro}
Intro to my topic. Here's a figure to clarify. (\fref{fig:introFig})

\begin{figure}[!b]
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \fbox{Figure graphics that have 2 panels in one PDF file.}
      \captionlistentry{A}\label{subfig:introFigA}
      \captionlistentry{B}\label{subfig:introFigB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[Full Caption Title for ToC]{Caption title appears in text and is much longer than what appears in the LoF, which is good because this is long.
        \subref{subfig:introFigA} Explaining the first part, then\ldots
        \subref{subfig:introFigB} Explaining the second. But how do I get subcaption titles into the LoF?
        }\label{fig:introFig}
\end{figure}

for an idea of what I want my LoF to look like, see \fref{fig:example}.

\begin{figure}[!b]
ToC Title for Fig 1.1 \dotfill \pageref{fig:introFig}

\hspace{\LoFindent} subtitle for subfig A

\hspace{\LoFindent} subtitle for subfig B

ToC Title for Fig 1.2 \dotfill \pageref{fig:example}

\caption{What I want my LoF to look like (content-wise, of course)}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But to my surprise I found out that I totally forgot to adapt `\captionlistentry` to my `subcaption` package.

However, I just did this and you'll find the actual version of the `caption` package at https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tex/

See also: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/13/

While the example code above works fine now, these are the things which still have to be done by me:

1. Offer (and document) `\subcaptionlistentry` additionally
2. Add a note to the documentation that the counter `lofdepth` offered by the `memoir` document class will be respected, i.e. needs to be set to at least a value of 2
3. Put this stuff to CTAN

I'll keep you informed about the further progress...

Comment: Your code works to insert the subcaptions into the LoF, but is there a way to do this without them also being marked with a page number (and dotted line to the page number)? Since they are subfigures, they'll all be on the same page. I'm hunting through the memoir documentation for an answer to this, but (as usual) I can't find an answer right away.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to remove the dots and pagenumbers by \let\stdl@subfigure\l@subfigure followed by \renewcommand*{\l@subfigure}[2]{{\def\@dotsep{1000} \stdl@subfigure{#1}{}}} (framed in \makeatletter and \makeatother of course)